# Proof of Saito criterion

Tags: reference-request, divisors

Does it exist another proof of saito's criterion for free divisors, other than the one in "K. Saito, Theory of logarithmic differential forms and logarithmic vector fields, J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo Sect. IA Math. 27 (1980), no. 2, pp. 265-291."?if yes, where?